# ¿Es correcta la frase "Los ejércitos lucharon en son durante tres meses"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, significado, preposiciones

¿Es correcta la siguiente frase?

> Los ejércitos lucharon **en son** durante tres meses.

¿Qué significa ***en son***?

Comment: Podríamos ayudarte mejor si nos das un poco más de contexto. Por ejemplo el resto del párrafo, o la frase inglesa original si estás traduciendo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No es correcta, no tiene sentido.

"Son" como sustantivo significa sonido o ritmo, o como verbo es la tercera persona del plural del verbo ser ("ellos son simpáticos").

"En son" es una expresión incompleta. La forma más frecuente es "en son de paz" que significa "sin ánimo de pelear".

Answer (score 2):

No es correcto del todo. Alternativas que se me ocurren:

> Los ejércitos lucharon durante tres meses.
>
> Los ejércitos lucharon **en X** durante tres meses.
>
> Los ejércitos lucharon en **son de Y** durante tres meses

Donde **X** es un lugar (ejemplo: "Los ejércitos lucharon en **Madrid** durante tres meses").

Donde **Y** es una forma de luchar (ejemplo: "Los ejércitos lucharon en **son de broma** durante tres meses").

Comment: "Los ejércitos lucharon _en_ son de broma durante tres meses" En este ejemplo ese _en_ esta de mas una posible opción correcta seria: "Los ejércitos **que** lucharon durante tres meses son de broma"

Comment: "Los ejércitos lucharon en son de broma durante tres meses" es correcto. La frase que has puesto también es correcta pero el significado es diferente.

Comment: Tenes razón, disculpa. Claramente no conocía todos los significados y usos de la palabra "son". Y me hacia mucho ruido.